# Scala combine Seq of Timestamps

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-collections

Hello I'm learning Scala and I have a Seq of object of the following case class:

```
case class HistoryCounter(time: DateTime, counter:Int)
```

Now I would like to combine the value of `counter` based on the timestamp `time`. To get the sum of all counters where `time` is on the same day or the same week.

How can you do this? Is one of the collection functions like fold or map capable of doing this?

Comment: I think `groupBy` is what you want followed by a `mapValues`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had a `List` of these case classes called `list`, one way to do this is like so:

```
  val counts = 
    list.groupBy(_.time).map{
      case (k, v) => (k, v.map(_.counter).sum)
    }
```

Or more succinctly:

```
list.groupBy(_.time).mapValues(_.map(_.counter).sum)
```

Comment: @DidierDuport, you can not call sum on `v`, it's not a List of ints but a List of `HistoryCounter`

Comment: Sorry, I should have left my comment and not done the edit. Fine as it is now. thanks